# Converting MS Word sentences into pictures

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have need where I am writing sentences in MS Word (any version is fine) in a foreign language (specifically Arabic and/or Urdu) with custom font and size and I would like convert those sentences to pictures using a script or something. This is because I need to post these pictures on a website where I cannot upload custom fonts or store them along with the webpage. Right now the way we do it is to crop pictures out of the word document. Is there way to do this in VBScript or any other scripting language?

Comment: This may not be an option but wanted to mention it anyway. Are you aware that all modern browsers support the Web Open Font Format (WOFF)? You should be able to specify a web font in your CSS that supports Arabic/Urdu (see [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) for some examples) and the client's browser should be able to download and use it.

Comment: @Bond I have edited the original question. I think one of the reasons I wanted this is because the site where I need to upload the content I can upload pictures but I cannot upload any custom fonts as its not under my control.

Comment: Select and copy text. Paste Special the text as a picture. Copy the picture, paste into paint.